# How to mod_rewrite a subdomain?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress blog in the folder `/public_html/blog/` and a subdomain pointing to it: `blog.domain.com`. Now I have changed the domain of my blog so it should be visited directly by `domain.com/blog` which worked fine. Also the subdomain still exists and redirects to to `domain.com/blog`. However, all my old links to my blog posts still point to `blog.domain.com/p/111` for example. How can I use a mod_rewrite rule so that when someone visits `blog.domain.com/xyz/xyz` they see `domain.com/blog/xyz/xyz` instead?

Comment: Googling tip: ["mod_rewrite rewrite old subdomain to path"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+mod_rewrite%20rewrite%20old%20subdomain%20to%20path&gws_rd=ssl) for further examples.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/blog/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: updated the answer - should be correct now - was misreading it before